# Twitter How to get user profile pic using Fabric plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am using Fabric plugin with Android studio after login I got session, username and userid. Also got email address. But can't find any option to fetch user profile pic.

```
  /

/inti twitter client
        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                System.out.println("twitter success"+result.data.getUserId()+result.data.getUserName());
                gettwitteremail();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
            }
        });

private void gettwitteremail(){
TwitterSession session =
        Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
String token = authToken.token;
String secret = authToken.secret;
TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();
authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result result) {
        // Do something with the result, which provides
        // the email address
        System.out.println("twitter sucess"+result.data);
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
        // Do something on failure
        System.out.println("twitter sucess"+exception.getMessage());
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

---

#### Fixed

Fixed by using following code

```
TwitterSession session =
                Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
String token = authToken.token;
String secret = authToken.secret;
TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient =  Twitter.getApiClient();
StatusesService twapiclient = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
twapiclient.userTimeline(twitteruserid,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
    @Override
    public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> listResult) {

        System.out.println("listResult"+listResult.data.size());
        System.out.println("listResult"+listResult.data.get(0).user);
        System.out.println("listResult"+listResult.data.get(0).user.profileImageUrl);
        userInfo.imageurl = listResult.data.get(0).user.profileImageUrl;
        
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(TwitterException e) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I Fixed , with the help of there rest api

Answer (score 3):

Try this code for fetch user profile pic.

```
 public void getTwitterData(final TwitterSession session) {
       MyTwitterApiClient tapiclient = new MyTwitterApiClient(session);
       tapiclient.getCustomService().show(session.getUserId(),
       new Callback<User>() {
           @Override
           public void success(Result<User> result) {

              TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
              String token = authToken.token;
              String secret = authToken.secret;
              name.setText(result.data.name);
              location.setText(result.data.location);
              new ImageDownloader(profileImageView)
              .execute(result.data.profileImageUrl);

              Log.d("Name", name);
              Log.d("city", location);

              }

              public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
              // Do something on failure
              exception.printStackTrace();
             }
        });

    ****************
         class MyTwitterApiClient extends TwitterApiClient {
            public MyTwitterApiClient(TwitterSession session) {
                super(session);
            }

            public CustomService getCustomService() {
                return getService(CustomService.class);
            }


        }

        interface CustomService {
            @GET("/1.1/users/show.json")
            void show(@Query("user_id") long id, Callback<User> cb);
        }

************
    class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public ImageDownloader(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String url = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return mIcon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```